# Flutter/Dart: speech to text (offline and continuous) for any language

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there any package that I can use to create an app that can process speech to text?

It should include the following features:

- offline speech to text
- continuous listening(10-30 minutes)
- recognizer would work for all languages that Android/IOS supports

So far I found this https://pub.dev/packages/speech_recognition but it says:

> the iOS API sends intermediate results, On my Android device, only the
>   final transcription is received
>
> Other limitations:  On iOS, by default the plugin is configured for
>   French, English, Russian, Spanish, Italian. On Android, without
>   additional installations, it will probably works only with the default
>   device locale.

Somebody tested this package and had good results? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text now. It is actively maintained and it works pretty good. I think some custom code can be written to make it listen continuously.

**Edit:**

As requested, please see the continuous listening logic below. I only used it as a proof of concept, so I wouldn't recommend it for production apps. As far as I know the Android API does not support continuous listening out of the box.

*SpeechRecognitionBloc*

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:template_mobile/core/sevices/speech_recognition_service.dart';
import 'package:template_mobile/core/state/event/speech_recognition_event.dart';
import 'package:template_mobile/core/state/state/speech_recognition_state.dart';

class SpeechRecognitionBloc
    extends Bloc<SpeechRecognitionEvent, SpeechRecognitionState> {
  final SpeechRecognitionService speechRecognitionService;

  SpeechRecognitionBloc({
    @required this.speechRecognitionService,
  }) : assert(speechRecognitionService != null) {
    speechRecognitionService.errors.stream.listen((errorResult) {
      add(SpeechRecognitionErrorEvent(
        error: "${errorResult.errorMsg} - ${errorResult.permanent}",
      ));
    });

    speechRecognitionService.statuses.stream.listen((status) {
      if (state is SpeechRecognitionRecognizedState) {
        var currentState = state as SpeechRecognitionRecognizedState;
        if (currentState.finalResult) {
          add(SpeechRecognitionStatusChangedEvent());
        }
      }
    });

    speechRecognitionService.words.stream.listen((speechResult) {
      add(SpeechRecognitionRecognizedEvent(
        words: speechResult.recognizedWords,
        finalResult: speechResult.finalResult,
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  SpeechRecognitionState get initialState =>
      SpeechRecognitionUninitializedState();

  @override
  Stream<SpeechRecognitionState> mapEventToState(
      SpeechRecognitionEvent event) async* {
    if (event is SpeechRecognitionInitEvent) {
      var hasSpeech = await speechRecognitionService.initSpeech();
      if (hasSpeech) {
        yield SpeechRecognitionAvailableState();
      } else {
        yield SpeechRecognitionUnavailableState();
      }
    }

    if (event is SpeechRecognitionStartPressEvent) {
      yield SpeechRecognitionStartPressedState();
      add(SpeechRecognitionStartEvent());
    }

    if (event is SpeechRecognitionStartEvent) {
      speechRecognitionService.startListening();
      yield SpeechRecognitionStartedState();
    }

    if (event is SpeechRecognitionStopPressEvent) {
      yield SpeechRecognitionStopPressedState();
      add(SpeechRecognitionStopEvent());
    }

    if (event is SpeechRecognitionStopEvent) {
      speechRecognitionService.stopListening();
      yield SpeechRecognitionStopedState();
    }

    if (event is SpeechRecognitionCancelEvent) {
      speechRecognitionService.cancelListening();
      yield SpeechRecognitionCanceledState();
    }

    if (event is SpeechRecognitionRecognizedEvent) {
      yield SpeechRecognitionRecognizedState(
          words: event.words, finalResult: event.finalResult);
      if (event.finalResult == true &&
          speechRecognitionService.statuses.value == 'notListening') {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50));
        add(SpeechRecognitionStatusChangedEvent());
      }
    }

    if (event is SpeechRecognitionErrorEvent) {
      yield SpeechRecognitionErrorState(error: event.error);
      // Just for UI updates for the state to propagates
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50));
      add(SpeechRecognitionInitEvent());
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50));
      add(SpeechRecognitionStartPressEvent());
    }

    if (event is SpeechRecognitionStatusChangedEvent) {
      yield SpeechRecognitionStatusState();
      add(SpeechRecognitionStartPressEvent());
    }
  }
}
```

*SpeechRecognitionService*

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_error.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';

class SpeechRecognitionService {
  final SpeechToText speech = SpeechToText();

  var errors = StreamController<SpeechRecognitionError>();
  var statuses = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  var words = StreamController<SpeechRecognitionResult>();

  var _localeId = '';

  Future<bool> initSpeech() async {
    bool hasSpeech = await speech.initialize(
      onError: errorListener,
      onStatus: statusListener,
    );

    if (hasSpeech) {
      var systemLocale = await speech.systemLocale();
      _localeId = systemLocale.localeId;
    }

    return hasSpeech;
  }

  void startListening() {
    speech.stop();
    speech.listen(
        onResult: resultListener,
        listenFor: Duration(minutes: 1),
        localeId: _localeId,
        onSoundLevelChange: null,
        cancelOnError: true,
        partialResults: true);
  }

  void errorListener(SpeechRecognitionError error) {
    errors.add(error);
  }

  void statusListener(String status) {
    statuses.add(status);
  }

  void resultListener(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    words.add(result);
  }

  void stopListening() {
    speech.stop();
  }

  void cancelListening() {
    speech.cancel();
  }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to make it listen continuously?

Comment: Yes, sort of. I was able to smoothly restart the speech after each result/error. Of course it is not ideal, but as far as I understand the Android API does not support continuous recognition.

Comment: could you please upload your code as a gist or something so I could use it?

Comment: @SIMMORSAL I updated the answer with the requested code.

Comment: Thank you. Quick question, does this code make it so that each time it activates and deactivates, the default speech sounds play?

Comment: @SIMMORSAL I didn't hear any sound when playing with it. Maybe the phone volume was off :)

Comment: Chris could you please provide your full code cause am getting alot of errors, am working on my final school project and i need the feature of able to run speech recognition continues on the background for android and ios, could you please help me and thanks in advance :)

Comment: It missing two files that i need them to test your logic please provide them.

Answer (score 10):

A more straightforward solution using flutter [speech_to_text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text) library on version `5.6.1` and without using `bloc` library as in previous answers.

Basically, whenever the statusListener method is called with the `done` status we call the Listen method again.

###### main.dart

```cs
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_error.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_recognition_result.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final SpeechToText _speechToText = SpeechToText();
  bool _speechEnabled = false;
  bool _speechAvailable = false;
  String _lastWords = '';
  String _currentWords = '';
  final String _selectedLocaleId = 'es_MX';

  printLocales() async {
    var locales = await _speechToText.locales();
    for (var local in locales) {
      debugPrint(local.name);
      debugPrint(local.localeId);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSpeech();
  }

  void errorListener(SpeechRecognitionError error) {
    debugPrint(error.errorMsg.toString());
  }

  void statusListener(String status) async {
    debugPrint("status $status");
    if (status == "done" && _speechEnabled) {
      setState(() {
        _lastWords += " $_currentWords";
        _currentWords = "";
        _speechEnabled = false;
      });
      await _startListening();
    }
  }

  /// This has to happen only once per app
  void _initSpeech() async {
    _speechAvailable = await _speechToText.initialize(
        onError: errorListener,
        onStatus: statusListener
    );
    setState(() {});
  }

  /// Each time to start a speech recognition session
  Future _startListening() async {
    debugPrint("=================================================");
    await _stopListening();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
    await _speechToText.listen(
        onResult: _onSpeechResult,
        localeId: _selectedLocaleId,
        cancelOnError: false,
        partialResults: true,
        listenMode: ListenMode.dictation
    );
    setState(() {
      _speechEnabled = true;
    });
  }

  /// Manually stop the active speech recognition session
  /// Note that there are also timeouts that each platform enforces
  /// and the SpeechToText plugin supports setting timeouts on the
  /// listen method.
  Future _stopListening() async {
    setState(() {
      _speechEnabled = false;
    });
    await _speechToText.stop();
  }

  /// This is the callback that the SpeechToText plugin calls when
  /// the platform returns recognized words.
  void _onSpeechResult(SpeechRecognitionResult result) {
    setState(() {
      _currentWords = result.recognizedWords;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Speech Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: const Text(
                'Recognized words:',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Text(
                  _lastWords.isNotEmpty
                      ? '$_lastWords $_currentWords'
                      : _speechAvailable
                      ? 'Tap the microphone to start listening...'
                      : 'Speech not available',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed:
        _speechToText.isNotListening ? _startListening : _stopListening,
        tooltip: 'Listen',
        child: Icon(_speechToText.isNotListening ? Icons.mic_off : Icons.mic),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's really cool! In general, it works fine. But do you also have an idea of fallback strategy? The code you provided doesn't listen anymore after an error occurs. I modified errorListener() as 
```
 void errorListener(SpeechRecognitionError error) async {
    debugPrint(error.errorMsg.toString());
    if (_speechEnabled) {
      await _startListening();
    }
  }
```
But, somehow the callstack doesn't come into the errorListener :( Do you have any idea on fallback strategy?

Comment: Could you explain how to reproduce your error?

Comment: With your code, start the api and don't say anything for a while ( like 10 seconds)! The mic button would still be listening state but the prompt is no more get updated. The app seems to stuck if an error occurs.

Comment: I/flutter ( 4955): status listening
I/flutter ( 4955): status notListening
I/flutter ( 4955): status done
I/flutter ( 4955): =================================================
I/flutter ( 4955): status listening

the app says it's still listening but nothing happens more than 10 mins.

Comment: I think that's because cancelOnError is set to true, try it with false value.

Comment: @임정섭 did it work with [Faizan Ahmad suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060889/flutter-dart-speech-to-text-offline-and-continuous-for-any-language#comment130350746_73597058)?

Comment: @SergioG Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Oh, I rebuilded the app and @FaizanAhmad 's solution seems to work!
I add my code.
https://gist.github.com/jsrimr/09af9516ee1c5907453635b03ce885ae

Comment: Amazing!! I will update the code posted here then

Comment: this is amazing, however when I use this in the main page of my app everything works fine, but when I use it in a "secondary page" it doesn't work. Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

https://pub.dev/packages/speech_recognition is the best choice.
it is based on [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer) and offers offline speech to text.

Continuous listening is not possible. Even the paid, online [Cloud Speech-to-Text API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text) doesn't allow this, because it is to dangerous (misuse etc).

On iOS, by default the plugin is configured for French, English, Russian, Spanish, Italian, but you can add a missing language into the swift source file.

So finally you will not found a better plugin for speech recognition, even if it is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to write custom platform specific code https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels, for Android you can use https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-android-demo to get exactly what you want.

Another alternative is to build your own keyboard IME to use voice typing as suggested in [How Can I Implement Google Voice Typing In My Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413692/how-can-i-implement-google-voice-typing-in-my-application).