# Intercepting audio blobs or saving audio to a file with Azure Speech to Text on Android

Tags: android, azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

Is it possible to save the transcribed audio to a file or even intercept the audio blobs using the Java SDK ? Currently I'm trying with `com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech:client-sdk:1.19.0`

I'm looking at the SDK but doesn't have any clear documentation on how to achieve this.

I tried the following without any success:

```
SpeechRecognizer(config, AudioConfig.fromWavFileOutput(file.toString()))
```

```
Connection connection = Connection.fromRecognizer(reco);
connection.messageSent...  --- this is missing from the Java SDK
```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: also, if anyone knows a good Flutter plugin or Dart library with this, it would be cool

Comment: You can refer to [Speech to text from Azure](https://pub.dev/packages/tts_azure) and [Flutter/Dart: speech to text (offline and continuous) for any language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58060889/flutter-dart-speech-to-text-offline-and-continuous-for-any-language)

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub repository [Cognitive-Speech-STT-Android](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Android)  will provide the complete guidance for Azure Speech to Text on Android.